# Magento's extension installation

Tags: php, magento, module, installation

i want to install magento extension but not from the magento connect how can i do this 
i have the module(extension) code and i allready install the sample data in magento installtion

Answer (score 1):

From [magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/magento_filesystem_permissions):

Alternatively, if you do not like to make all files and folders writable to the web service, it is possible to install and upgrade Magento from shell, using command line PEAR instructions, such as:

```
# all commands are to be ran from the root Magento folder.
# help on all available PEAR commands:
./pear help

# set preferred stability for installed/upgraded packages (alpha,beta,stable):
./pear config-set preferred_state beta

# initial installation from downloader package:
./pear mage-setup .
./pear install magento-core/Mage_All_Latest

# install additional extension:
./pear install magento-community/Some_Extension

# list available upgrades
./pear list-upgrades

# upgrade a package
./pear upgrade magento-core/Mage_Package

# uninstall a package
./pear uninstall magento-community/Unwanted_Package
```

The pear script should be located under `magento/downloader/pearlib`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason i have better luck with the mage functions, such as

```
./pear upgrade-all 
./mage sync-pear 
./mage upgrade-all
```

if you get a conflicting error, then run

```
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides installing Magento extension via Magento Connect Manager, you can install manually by using the "Magento Extension Downloader" tool here: http://miragedesign.net/tools/download-magento-extension/

Basically, you just need to enter the key and click Get Extension button, then download the "ready to use" zip file, extract all the content of the extension folder to your Magento installation root, clear cache and that's all!!!

A more detail guide can be found here: http://miragedesign.net/newss/download-magento-extension-directly/

Hope it's useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on how your extension was packaged(occurred), e.g. pear package(most likely you downloaded extension from magento website or purchased from professional vendor) or regular archive(purchased from some junior or amateurish vendor):

- installing pear package:

  ./pear install Foo_FooBar-0.1.0.tgz
- installing from regular archive: usually you just need to extract archive into the magento root, otherwise look for instruction inside archive or request from vendor

See also [installing magento via ssh](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh)

Thanks.