# create an .xls file in magento 1.7 programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, xls

I need to create a `.xls` file in Magento and send it to the client for download. I achieved this for PDF, and it works fine but for .xls file I can't seem to create it.

How to create .xls file in Magento? Can you provide solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Qazi Mustafa...my answer is valid means make appreciate me and also upvote for me..

Answer (score 1):

Here magento have some free extension are present. 
   If you want to display .xls file format means Install this extension..
Here that link:
[Magento extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/perfect-excel-export-management-report-3508.html)
this is procedure to install magento extension[magento extenstion installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392027/magentos-extension-installation)
If you want to know any description this link helps for you.
[enter link description here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/298088/)